# Jquery plugin FlipClockjs Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I just started using the **FlipClock js** using [this:](http://flipclockjs.com/faces/daily-counter)

```
var clock;
$(document).ready(function() {
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(3600 * 24 * 3, {
        clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
        countdown: true,
        autostart: true
    });
});
```

The clock does display,but the timer is not working.

ie: The clock timer doesn't flip.

I tried replacing the clockFace to **"HourlyCounter"** and it worked perfectly.
But doesn't work on **"DailyCounter".**

Is this a bug or is it just me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bad if condition inside flipclock.js is the culprit at around line 482 inside the method

```
flip: function(time, doNotAddPlayClass)
```

Please change the following code snipet

```
if (!t.factory.time.time instanceof Date) {
    if(!t.factory.countdown) {
        t.factory.time.time++;
    }
    else {
        if(t.factory.time.time <= 0) {
            t.factory.stop();
        }

        t.factory.time.time--;
    }
}
```

to

```
if (!(t.factory.time.time instanceof Date)) { //-- would satisfy condition in this case.
    if(!t.factory.countdown) {
        t.factory.time.time++;
    }
    else {
        if(t.factory.time.time <= 0) {
            t.factory.stop();
        }

        t.factory.time.time--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Cookies?
use **clock.getTime()** to get the last date time data before user leave your page.